# Report typescript errors as warnings in Visual Studio and don't fail the build

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I want to typecheck existing javascript code. To that end, I have specified the following tsconfig. Running `tsc` results in a couple of hundred errors, which show up in Visual Studio when I do a build. However those errors now also fail the build. As the code is currently functioning, I want to postpone resolving those errors. I want the errors to be reported as warnings, such that the build will continue and we can gradually improve the javascript.

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

```xml
//csproj (abbreviated)
<Project>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.6</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
</Project>
...
```

Example msbuild output:

```
...
file.js:153:33 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
========== Build: 14 succeeded, 1 failed, 23 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I think msbuild watches the output for the word 'error'. When it does it flags an error.

Comment: These errors are identified by the msbuild compilation, and you can't ignore them and turn them into warnings. Or you can try to rewrite or disable the error-detecting task of the msbuild build tool.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, msbuild's `exec` command searches the output for the word `error`, and if found will emit a build error.

Which it seems that this linter *.targets file is doing.
And seems to be corroborated here:
[Does the MSBuild Exec task search STDOUT for the string "error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117302/does-the-msbuild-exec-task-search-stdout-for-the-string-error)

But really:
If you want to postpone fixing those errors, I see no choice but to simply rip out your linter from your *.csproj files completely. I mean why put in the linter only to ignore it and defer your technical debt?

In that case I'd simply put take that code you shared, and pull it out of the .csproj file and put it into a separate, standalone msbuild file and run it separately.

Comment: I'm using the build target provided by Visual Studio, so there's no `Exec` in my `csproj`. The compilation is handled by an element named `<VsTsc ... />`. I'm not entirely sure where/how that element is implemented.

Comment: Regarding "I mean why put in the linter only to ignore it and defer your technical debt?". Simply; to make the technical debt visible to the team, using our build stats and the like.

Comment: the call to <Exec> is coming in through the targets file that you <imported>

Comment: I dug into the definition of the import; it turns out the call to the compiler is handled through a Task (`<UsingTask TaskName="TypeScript.Tasks.VsTsc" AssemblyFile="$(TypeScriptTaskAssembly)" />` and `<TypeScriptTaskAssembly Condition="'$(TypeScriptTaskAssembly)' == ''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)TypeScript.Tasks.dll</TypeScriptTaskAssembly>`, see also [MSBuild Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2019).